# How to calculate a correlation in excel based on multiple conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, correlation

How to calculate a correlation in excel based on multiple conditions?

| Zone | Car | Max Speed | Complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Renault | 120 | 0 |
| 2 | Audi | 15 | 1 |
| 3 | Renault | 10 | 0 |
| 4 | Audi | 75 | 1 |

I want to see a correlation between max speed and complete ( 0 means incomplete, 1 means complete), for renault in zone 1.

I have tried this:

```
=CORREL(IF(AND(A2:A5="1",B2:B5="Renault"), C2:C5), IF(And(A2:A5="1",B2:B5="Renault"), D2:D5))
```

It does not work.

Comment: It will give error because for zone 1, you have `0` zero in `Complete` column.

Comment: But it works if I remove the and statement.  And it allows me to check correlation between C and D.

Comment: Because, without condition you have other value than zero.